# linux function openat vs open, what does "at" mean?

Tags: c, linux

I know how to use the two functions, but I do not know what the suffix "at" means. Does it represent the abbreviation of "another"?

Comment: No, it's literally the English word `at`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At means that the working directory considered for the open call is at the given file descriptor, passed as the parameter. The *at() family of functions are useful so that all path relative operations refer to the same file inode, even if it changes name or someone replaces it.